# Need to restart my script from beginning when ctrl c detected using sigint

Tags: bash

I need it to restart the countdown from 10 when ctrl c is pressed using the trap. I can get it to restart once and it currently does that when I press ctrl c it restarts from 10. But it only does it once, I need it to do it every single time ctrl c is pressed restart from 10 but can't get it to do that.

I have tried googling

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script demonstrates how to trap signals and handle them using functions

# Task: Add traps for the INT and QUIT signals. If the script receives an INT signal,
#       reset the count to the maximum and tell the user they are not allowed to interrupt
#       the count. If the script receives a QUIT signal, tell the user they found the secret
#       to getting out of the script and exit immediately.

# Task: Explain in a comment how the line with the word moose in it works.
function cleanquit {
  logger -t `basename "$0"` -i -p user.info -s "You found the secret to exiting the script"
  exit 1
}
trap cleanquit SIGQUIT

function cleanint {
  logger -t `basename "$0"` -i -p user.info -s "You are too early, try again"
  countdown
  trap - signals
}
trap cleanint SIGINT



#### Variables
programName="$(basename $0)" # used by error_functions.sh
sleepTime=1 # delay used by sleeptime
numberOfSleeps=10 # how many sleeps to wait for before quitting for inactivity

#### Functions

# This function will send an error message to stderr
# Usage:
#   error-message ["some text to print to stderr"]
#
function error-message {
        echo "${programName}: ${1:-Unknown Error - a moose bit my sister once...}" >&2
}

# This function will send a message to stderr and exit with a failure status
# Usage:
#   error-exit ["some text to print" [exit-status]]
#
function error-exit {
        error-message "$1"
        exit "${2:-1}"
}
function usage {
        cat <<EOF
Usage: ${programName} [-h|--help ] [-w|--waittime waittime] [-n|--waitcount waitcount]
Default waittime is 1, waitcount is 10
EOF
}

#### Main Program

# Process command line parameters
function countdown {
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -w | --waittime )
            shift
            sleepTime="$1"
            ;;
        -n | --waitcount)
            shift
            numberOfSleeps="$1"
            ;;
        -h | --help )
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        * )
            usage
            error-exit "$1 not a recognized option"
    esac
    shift
done

if [ ! $numberOfSleeps -gt 0 ]; then
    error-exit "$numberOfSleeps is not a valid count of sleeps to wait for signals"
fi

if [ ! $sleepTime -gt 0 ]; then
    error-exit "$sleepTime is not a valid time to sleep while waiting for signals"
fi

sleepCount=$numberOfSleeps

while [ $sleepCount -gt 0 ]; do
    echo "Waiting $sleepCount more times for signals"
    sleep $sleepTime
    sleepCount=$((sleepCount - 1))
done
echo "Wait counter expired, exiting peacefully"
}

countdown
```

I expect it to restart the script from 10 when ctrl c every single time but it only does that once

Comment: use ```trap cleanint EXIT``` and try.so it will not exit.

Comment: i tried to edit that into the script but it didn't do anything, it detects the ctrl c and continue the script but doesn't restart the countdown back to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using this code

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script demonstrates how to trap signals and handle them using functions

# Task: Add traps for the INT and QUIT signals. If the script receives an INT signal,
#       reset the count to the maximum and tell the user they are not allowed to interrupt
#       the count. If the script receives a QUIT signal, tell the user they found the secret
#       to getting out of the script and exit immediately.

# Task: Explain in a comment how the line with the word moose in it works.
trap reset 2
trap foundSecret 3

function foundSecret {
  echo "You found the secret for getting out of the script"
  exit
}

#### Variables
programName="$(basename $0)" # used by error_functions.sh
sleepTime=1 # delay used by sleeptime
numberOfSleeps=10 # how many sleeps to wait for before quitting for inactivity

#### Functions

# This function will send an error message to stderr
# Usage:
#   error-message ["some text to print to stderr"]
#
function error-message {
        echo "${programName}: ${1:-Unknown Error - a moose bit my sister once...}" >&2
}

# This function will send a message to stderr and exit with a failure status
# Usage:
#   error-exit ["some text to print" [exit-status]]
#
function error-exit {
        error-message "$1"
        exit "${2:-1}"
}
function usage {
        cat <<EOF
Usage: ${programName} [-h|--help ] [-w|--waittime waittime] [-n|--waitcount waitcount]
Default waittime is 1, waitcount is 10
EOF
}

#### Main Program

# Process command line parameters
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -w | --waittime )
            shift
            sleepTime="$1"
            ;;
        -n | --waitcount)
            shift
            numberOfSleeps="$1"
            ;;
        -h | --help )
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        * )
            usage
            error-exit "$1 not a recognized option"
    esac
    shift
done

if [ ! $numberOfSleeps -gt 0 ]; then
    error-exit "$numberOfSleeps is not a valid count of sleeps to wait for signals"
fi

if [ ! $sleepTime -gt 0 ]; then
    error-exit "$sleepTime is not a valid time to sleep while waiting for signals"
fi

sleepCount=$numberOfSleeps

function reset {
  echo "You are not allowed to interrupt the count"
  sleepCount=$(($NumberOfSleeps+11))
}

while [ $sleepCount -gt 0 ]; do
    echo "Waiting $sleepCount more times for signals"
    sleep $sleepTime
    sleepCount=$((sleepCount - 1))
done
echo "Wait counter expired, exiting peacefully"
```